# Toggle collapse different divs on click with VueJS v-on:click and Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Is it possible using VueJS and vanilla JS to collapse one of many divs?

I have data within separate cards featuring a title and a body - I am wanting the body of the card to collapse/expand when the title is clicked.

VueJS is being used, and I would like to keep JQuery out of it for the time being, focusing on vanilla JS.

See this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1wh75v9/)** for an example of what it looks like. Please bare in mind that I am FULLY AWARE of not using the same ID for multiple elements - this was a quick demo for illustration purposes.

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="title" @click="toggle"><span class="toggleIcon" id="toggleIcon">{{toggleIcon}}</span>Toggle This Section</div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="body" id="toggle">
        <img style="height:100px" src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Pkmq1nm3skO0-j693JTMd7RL0Zk=/0x0:2012x1341/1200x800/filters:focal(0x0:2012x1341)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/47070706/google2.0.0.jpg">
     </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have at the moment is that I can collapse a div, but not individual divs.

Comment: I know you said you're fully aware that you shouldn't use the same ID for multiple elements but this is exactly what's causing the issue in the fiddle. It's targeting `#toggle` in the method but that will always match the first element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember Vue.js is data driven, so changes in the DOM should reflect underlying data changes. In your case your case you should wrap the cards up in a component, so they track their own individual state, and then use a flag with `v-show` to show and hide the section:

**Vue Instance**

```
Vue.component('card', {
  template: '#card',
  methods: {
    toggle() {
     this.showSection = !this.showSection
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showSection: true, // Flag to show section
      imageUrl: 'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Pkmq1nm3skO0-j693JTMd7RL0Zk=/0x0:2012x1341/1200x800/filters:focal(0x0:2012x1341)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/47070706/google2.0.0.jpg',
      toggleIcon: '+'
    }
  }
})
```

**Markup**

```
  <div class="section">
    <div class="title" v-on:click="toggle">
      <span class="toggleIcon" id="toggleIcon">{{toggleIcon}}</span> Toggle This Section
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <!-- BIND v-show to the showSection data property to reflect changes -->
    <div class="body" v-show="showSection">
      <img v-bind:src="imageUrl">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Note that I'm not touching the DOM, I'm just toggling the `showSection` flag and Vue is updating the DOM for me.

And here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/j1wh75v9/1/

#### Passing different content to the cards

If you want to pass different content to each card you can use a [slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots):

```
<template id="card">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="title" v-on:click="toggle">
      <span class="toggleIcon" id="toggleIcon">{{toggleIcon}}</span> Toggle This Section
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="body" v-show="showSection">
      <!-- Add slot details here -->
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Slots allow you to insert content into your component from the parent, as I'm only using a single slot, anything that I place between my component tags gets injected where I placed my slot tags in my component, so:

```
<card>I'm a card</card>
<card> Im another card</card>
```

In these examples, the message between the card tags will be added to the slot. Slots get compiled in the parent scope, not the scope of the component, so if you want to use data properties then they must be available in the parent, similarly you cannot access data properties and methods in the component from the slot data.

Here's the JSFiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/ew1epg61/

Comment: Good answer. Just one thing: I would use something like `:class="{hidden: showSection}"`, instead of `v-show`. With toggling class on element, one can easily add animations/effects to process of toggling visibility.

Comment: Craig, you are a life saver!
I even tried it using an extra piece of functionality to change the + to a - on the title when expanded or not and it works!Top man!

Comment: @waldemarcle I prefer the `v-show` flag. In terms of animation, I just would use a [transition](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) for that, which is designed to work with `v-show`.

Comment: @craig_h - One question for you... If I am not wanting to create many different components (as I would have to refactor my code) and wanted to implement your solution in the standard layout as in my Fiddle... How could I do this? I applied it in the standard layout and it now toggles ALL sections as expected. I have also tried getting the function to pass an argument: toggle($event) and using e.target.showSection = !e.target.showSection, however this is not working... Any thoughts?

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you refactor into components because that is how Vue was designed to work, also you are still trying to access the DOM directly to show and hide sections, you should avoid this as it can cause problems down the line. Instead you should to bind each section to a separate flag, which you can place in an array or an object and then toggle that particular flag: https://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/9pLt3L7c/

Comment: Thanks for the info @craig_h - I've only picked up using Vue this week, so it's all a bit new. I'll start thinking about abstracting everything out into components in future!

Comment: @physicsboy No worries, we all had to start somewhere and the transition in to thinking in a data-driven way and understanding Vue's intricacies can take a little time.

Comment: @craig_h - I was just having another look at your original Fiddle now that I've gotten around to refactoring my code... I probably didn't explain during my original question - or maybe I'm just realising now... I am having multiple different components being imported to be output on the index.html - Imagine that each component holds the HTML for its own card & content - How would one refactor your code to toggle these? Your code assumes that both cards are created from the same template etc...

Comment: @craig_h What if in the accordion, you want only one item to be open at a time? With your approach, each item behaves as an independent toggle.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to wrap my head around this, such a trivial thing to do, but wanted to keep it the "VueJS" way...

Answer (score 0):

This another take on the collapsable card (with slots) similar to @craig_h:

```
<template>
  <div class="section">
    <div :class="[isActive ? 'active' : '', 'collapsible']" v-on:click="toggle">
      Toggle This Section <span class="toggleIcon" id="toggleIcon">{{ toggleIcon }}</span>
    </div>
    <div :class="[isActive ? 'block' : 'none', 'content']" v-show="isActive">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CollapsableCard',
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: false,
      toggleIcon: '+',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #d8f8ea;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eefcf6;
}
</style>
```